# flexdashboard (storyboard: true) not working when runtime: shiny added

Tags: r, storyboard, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to use `Rmarkdown`, `flexdashboard` (with the option `storyboard: true`) and also `shiny`. Everything works fine until I add `runtime: shiny`. Then the frame tabs move faster than expected and even disappear.

I've tried two ways of specifying the storyboard mode, by adding `storyboard: true` (commented out in the example code below) to the YAML and by adding the `{.storyboard}` class to the page I want laid out as a storyboard. Same result.

You can see the different behaviour just by commenting in and out `runtime: shiny` in the code below.

Any ideas of what I'm missing? Thanks for your help.

---

````
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    #storyboard: true
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```


Analysis {.storyboard}
=========================================

### Frame 1
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 1


### Frame 2
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 2


### Frame 3
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 3


### Frame 4
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 4


### Frame 5
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 5


### Frame 6
```{r}
```
***
Commentary for frame 6
````

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you described with this code.  Could you confirm that this code produces the error?  Is everything up to date?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ian. I just updated all packages to their latest version and still get the same result. I'm using R version 3.3.2 and RStudio version 1.0.44 on a Windows 7 machine. I can't update R/RStudio versions at work but I'll check at home later.

Comment: How odd???  It works fine on both my home and work PC. And in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.  It must be something specific to your machine...  Wish I could help more.

Comment: depending on what you're trying to do, a storyboard may not be the best option. despite that, i could not solve your problem. it looks like shiny really speeds up the frame tabs.

Comment: Try comparing sessionInfo's with computers that have it running well. Maybe you just didn't update something that you thought you did.

Comment: I have the same issue. But it's likely more a browser issue as it works perfect in Chrome or Firefox. It has the described problem (fast frame tabs) in Safari and Rstudio Viewer.